# It's an expected label or It's an label expected. what's the difference?

Tags: meaning, word-order

Can anyone help me analyze the difference between the following two sentences?

> - It's an expected label.
> - It's a label expected.

Comment: (i) is more-or-less normal English; by contrast, (ii) is super weird. It's possible, but only under some unusual circumstances.

Comment: Dawn is a known criminal. Dawn is a criminal known to the police. BUT *Dawn is a criminal known. (except, possibly, in Gilbert & Sullivan)

Answer (score 0):

The correct one is "It's an expected label".

It sounds correct and is correct in most situations. Label expected can be used rarely, but it's best to stick to expected label.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've a further question. Can I think "it's an our expected label" = "it's an label expected by us" = "it an label that is expected by us"?

Comment: @TechnorcLuke- That would be: *It's our expected label.*  Also note that it changes from *an* to *a* based on the word following:  ***a l***abel,  ***an e***xpected.